# How can i write if elif statement in one line in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

How to write if elif statement in python?
i want to write like this, but in one line:

```
def Add(datatype, *elements):
    if datatype == 'int':
        answer = 0
    elif datatype == 'string':
        answer = ''
```

but when i write : `answer = 0 if datatype == 'int' else '' if datatype == 'string'` i get problem, what's the problem?

i want to write one line if elif statement in one line without else statement.

Comment: What value would you want assigned to *answer* if *datatype* is neither 'int' nor 'string'?

Comment: *"what's the problem?"* - we don't know because you didn't add the error message you get to your question. Please always add the error message, say what you observe, etc. Makes it easier to understand your question and you'll get better answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you had already defined `answer` in another place, and you just don't want to change it if it doesn't answer any of you conditions, you can do:

```
answer = 0 if datatype == 'int' else '' if datatype == 'string' else answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary indexing:

```
def add(datatype, *elements):
    answer = {
        'int': 0,
        'string': ''
    }.get(datatype)
```

Comment: This is a good pattern but implies that *answer* should be assigned None if *datatype* is neither 'int' nor 'string'. Unfortunately, OP has not stated what should happen in such a case

Answer (score 0):

```
def Add(datatype, *elements):
    result = {'int' : 0, 'string': ''}[datatype] + sum(element)
    return result
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for writing an answer. You should [edit] your answer and add "code fences" around your code or indent it by four spaces to apply a `code` layout. Also, great answers usually consist of code and a little bit of descriptive text that explains what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to write if-else statement in one line without else statement, you can do that with the help of dictionary to map the datatypes and get method.

like-

```
def Add(datatype, *elements):
    answer = {"int": 0, "string": ""}.get(datatype, None)
    return answer
```

explaination-

- if **datatype** is `int` it returns `0`
- if **datatype** is `string`, it returns `empty string`
- for any other **datatype** it returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

emphasized textThe issue you're facing is due to the nested ternary expressions. The correct syntax for a one-liner without an else statement in this case is to use parentheses to clarify the order of evaluation.

```
datatype = 'int'
answer = 0 if datatype == 'int' else '' if datatype == 'string' else None
print(answer)

datatype = 'string'
answer = 0 if datatype == 'int' else '' if datatype == 'string' else None
print(answer)

datatype = 'float'
answer = 0 if datatype == 'int' else '' if datatype == 'string' else None
print(answer)
```

it checks if the datatype is 'int', and if true, assigns 0. If false, it checks if the datatype is 'string', and if true, assigns an empty string. If both conditions are false, it assigns None